# How to use CopyToDataTable with two datatable queries in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datatable, row

How to use CopyToDataTable with two datatable queries in VB.NET?.
should under Employee Information not appear column "GENDER" like the sign I marked warning red and under Gender Information do not appear for column "EMPLOYEE ID" and column "FULL NAME" like the sign I marked warning red .
It should be that the total pages are 83 + 1 blank pages, so a total of 84 pages instead of 166+1 blank pages, so a total of 167 pages

Is there something wrong with my code?

Thanks

```
Private Sub GeneratePayslip()
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        report.Clear()
        Dim query1 = "SELECT tblemployee.Empid AS [EMPLOYEE ID] ,tblemployee.Name AS [FULL NAME] FROM tblabsent INNER JOIN tblemployee ON tblabsent.EMPID = tblemployee.EMPID"
        Using adapter1 As New OleDbDataAdapter(query1, con)
            adapter1.Fill(dt)
        End Using
        Dim query2 = "SELECT tblemployee.GENDER FROM tblabsent INNER JOIN tblemployee ON tblabsent.EMPID = tblemployee.EMPID"
        Using adapter2 As New OleDbDataAdapter(query2, con)
            adapter2.Fill(dt)
        End Using
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            report.AddHorizontalRule()
            report.AddLineBreak()
  report.AddLineBreak()
            report.AddHorizontalRule()
            report.AddLineBreak()
            report.AddString("<h3>Employee Information</h3>")
            Dim table1 = {row}.CopyToDataTable()
            report.AddDataTable(table1)
            report.AddLineBreak()
            report.AddHorizontalRule()
            report.AddLineBreak()
            report.AddString("<h3>Gender Information</h3>")
            table1.Columns.Clear()
            Dim table2 = {row}.CopyToDataTable()
            report.AddDataTable(table2)
            report.NewPage()
        Next row
    End Sub
```

[image: output preview]
[image: result code from jmcilhinney]

Comment: It seems like your actual question here is how to combine those two queries into one, in which case this is purely a SQL none of the VB code is relevant in any way. You need to focus on the actual issue, which has nothing at all to do with `CopyToDataTable`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , Thank you for your feedback. If I merge into one SQL how can I split in the report as I want. I did 2 destination queries in order to split the results in the report

Comment: I may have misunderstood what you're asking. I think I get it now. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you should not be populating one `DataTable` using both queries but rather populating one each. Then, instead of a `For Each` loop, use a `For` loop. You can then use the loop counter as an index into both `DataTables` to get two rows to print on the current page, e.g.

```vb
adapter1.Fill(table1)
adapter2.Fill(table2)

For i = 0 To table1.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim row1 = table1.Rows(i)
    Dim row2 = table2.Rows(i)
    Dim tableCopy1 = {row1}.CopyToDataTable()
    Dim tableCopy2 = {row2}.CopyToDataTable()

    '...
Next
```

This assumes that both tables will contain the same number of rows.

Comment: Sorry I'm late replying. thanks your answer , the result is separate but the result from page 1 to page 3 is the same using your code. should appear each page corresponding to "EMPID" or "EMPLOYEE ID"

Comment: @user18, my code doesn't print anything. It's your code that doesn't work and we don't know what your new code actually looks like. If you're seeing data printed that you don't expect then that's almost certainly a data issue so you need to debug your code properly and actually look at the data BEFORE `CopyToDataTable` is even called. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: Your code successfull previews but same for page1 until page3, just from your code I don't call `CopyToDataTable` .From your answer where should I call `CopyToDataTable`

Comment: @user18, use some logic. Where was it used before? After getting a single row from the original `DataTable`. What does the code above do? It gets two single rows from the two original `DataTables`. Where does logic tell you that you should use `CopyToDataTable`?

Comment: @user18, I have updated my answer to add what I thought should have been the obvious next step.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `Dim row1 = table1.Rows(i)` I have error ` `table1 cannot be referred to before it is declared`  `Dim row2 = table2.Rows(i)` `table2 cannot be referred to before it is declared`

Comment: `Dim table1 = {row1}.CopyToDataTable()`  `Dim table2 = {row2}.CopyToDataTable()` If without the additional 2 lines of code then there is no error

Comment: @user18, I forgot that I'd used `table1` and `table2` as names for the original `DataTables`, so I just changed the names of new `DataTables`. You probably ought to have been able to work that out. You probably shouldn't be using `table1` and `table2` anyway. They are just part of an example. You should be using descriptive names at all times in your own code.

Comment: Your answer went perfectly.